# How to set $inc in a mongoose model instance when using .save()?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const urlSchema = new Schema({
  original_url: String,
  short_url: Number
});
```

Then I do this:

```
let urlInstance = new Url({ original_url: url, { $inc: { 'short_url': 1 }} });

    urlInstance.save((err, doc) => {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      console.log("saved ", doc);
      res.json(doc);
    });
```

also tried it like this:

```
let urlInstance = new Url({ original_url: url });

    urlInstance.save(({ $inc: { 'short_url': 1 }}), (err, doc) => {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      console.log("saved ", doc);
      res.json(doc);
    });
```

I don't know how to pass the `$inc` bit in without it complaining about syntax. What am I doing wrong here? Tried different ways and even using mongoose-sequence but seems like `$inc` should be easier?